# set value for double variable not same as expected in VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17, double, precision

I am trying to set double variable in Visual Studio 2019 with (c++17) but after compilation in debug mode I see another value but not as expected. Why?
for example

```
double v1 = 1.161050;
double v2 = 1.161190;
```

I added breakpoint and see next values:

```
v1 = 1.1610499999999999
v2 = 1.1611899999999999
```

Comment: Handy reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: You've run into a representation problem. A `double` on your system cannot represent 1.161050. The best it can do is give you a close enough 1.1610499999999999.

Comment: Close enough is not good, I need exactly the same value I set. How to make it correct?

Comment: @Pasha Don't use `double` if you require exact numbers. You can use an integer type with the convention that the number is implicitly divided by 1000000. aka Fixed point.

Comment: The fundamental reason is that not every decimal in the mathematical sense can be accurately represented in a finite number of digits in binary.